# Using command line tool SC.exe to append fail count on windows service failure

Tags: windows, windows-services, recovery

I am using SC.exe to configure windows service failure, I would like to run a command and pass in number of fails so far. I can check the 'Append fail to end of command line (/fail=%1%) in service properties, but I don't know how to do that from command line.

So far I have

```
SC failure "myservice" run/0/run/""/0 reset= 86400 commad="mycommand.exe"
```

but how to set that value?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying the command, just include `/fail=%1%` in the arguments. So, your command would read:

```
SC failure "myservice" run/0/run/""/0 reset= 86400 command="mycommand.exe /fail=%1%"
```

Note that your parameter will be something like `/fail=2`, so you'll need to trim your parameter to get the actual count.

I wasn't sure if you were still looking for how to do this since it's been a few months since you asked, but I thought I'd share since I had the same problem.